# How to connect a MIDI Keyboard and automatically write notes?

Tags: keyboard, music, jack, midi

I need to create a sheet while I play. How do I do this best? I want to just play the song and my PC does the rest, so I just need to print/play afterwards.

Comment: This should have anything MIDI related: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/MIDI-HOWTO-8.html  We probably need to brand of keyboard.

Comment: FWIW, mutlimedia is moderately specialized and Ubuntu Studio does a lot of the customizations for you.

Answer (score 1):

AS an aside, you may want to look at Ubuntu Studio if you are going do a lot of multimedia.

IMHO the easiest is musecore (also called mscore as the binary is mscore), it is probably included in Ubuntu Studio.

To install see https://musescore.org/en/node/75936

```
# To add the PPA if you don't already have it:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mscore-ubuntu/mscore-stable

# To install or upgrade MuseScore:
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install musescore
```

mscore will import a mdmi file.

https://musescore.com/

https://musescore.org/en/handbook/midi-import

or you can imput with your keyboard

https://musescore.org/en/handbook/note-entry

Or more specifically https://musescore.org/en/handbook/note-input#midi-keyboard

> MIDI keyboard You can also insert pitches using a MIDI keyboard.
>
> Connect your MIDI keyboard to the computer and switch the former on
>
> Start MuseScore (this must be done after the keyboard is switched on)
>
> Create a new score Click the rest (selecting it) in measure 1 to
> indicate where you want note input to begin Press N to enter note
> input mode Select a note duration such as 5 for quarter notes
> (crotchets), as described above Press a note on your MIDI keyboard The
> pitch should be added to your score.
>
> Note: The MIDI keyboard enters
> one note or chord at a time. This mode of note input (often called
> "step-time entry") is fast and reliable.

See linked documentation for details.